# GitLab -- Repository or object not found

Tags: git, macos, gitlab, git-lfs

I am using a Mac and using Terminal/GitKraken.

I am trying to push my project files to my groups GitLab. When I attempt to push, I get the error

" Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
batch response: Repository or object not found:
batch response: Repository or object not found: [https://gitlab.com/jacobhallum/dummyproject/objects/batch"](https://gitlab.com/jacobhallum/dummyproject/objects/batch%22)

I have tried everything I have found online to resolve this issue. I have uninstalled Git, uninstalled LFS, deleted the project, re-cloned, stashing, git reset hard HEAD~. Nothing has worked so far and I was hoping someone would be able to help me figure out a way around this.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Check first your remote:

```bash
cd /path/to/local/clone
git remote -v
```

It should be `https://gitlab.com/jacobhallum/dummyproject`, not `https://gitlab.com/jacobhallum/dummyproject/objects/batch`

Since I don't have access to the former URL, it mush be a private repository.
You will need to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) as a password to be able to push to it.

Comment: this link https://gitlab.com/jacobhallum/dummyproject/objects/batch is what git lfs push command outputs, it is not the remote url.

Comment: @Xiaoqi I agree: the remote URL seems wrong.